# Nuxt3 multiple optional route parameters

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am pretty new to nuxt and faced a task where i should use multiple optional route parameters. I want to keep my app as simple as it can be, so i would avoid using any additional package.
As i know nuxt3 routing depends on the folder structure, so here's the problem:

Lets say we got a  `/foo`   route, where can be 2 optional parameters,  `paramA`  and  `paramB`

This can be done with the following folder structure:

```
pages/
 -foo/
 --index.vue
 --[paramA]/
 ---index.vue
 ---[[paramB]].vue
```

It works, but this way the pages are duplicated for each param.

What is the best practice for this? Thank you

Comment: Why are You using double brackets, it's an issue and can cause also some problems with duplications

Comment: double bracket means optional in nuxt3,  single bracket is not optional.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers seem much more complicated than necessary. By using double squared brackets in the file and folder names you create an optional route parameter. (Single squared brackets will create a non optional route parameter).

So to create the URL `.../foo/:paramA?/:paramB?` you can use the following file structure.

```
pages/               (folder)
-foo/                (folder)
--[[paramA]]/        (folder)
---[[paramB]].vue    (file with actual page)
```

When navigating to URL `.../foo` the page `[[paramB]].vue` will be used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with custom routes:
`routes.js`

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
export const customRoutes = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: '/foo/:interest?/:id?',
    file: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/test.vue')
  }
];
```

And in the `nuxt.config.ts`

```
import { customRoutes } from "./routes.js";
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    hooks: {
    "pages:extend": (pages) => {
      customRoutes.forEach((customRoute) => {
        pages.push(customRoute)
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an URL with multiple parameters like this `mywebsite.com/param1/param2/param3`, you need this structure:

```
pages
└── [param1]
    └── [param2]
        └── [param3].vue
```

And to show it in the console, put this in `[param3].vue`

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
const route = useRoute();
console.log(route.params);
</script>
```

ref. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes

Answer (score 0):

For a complex routing system using multiple levels of paths, and components and sub-components, sub-sub-components, etc. And loading every parent/child components only if path params exists, you could use some function like this:

*~/extends/pages/RoutesCrud.ts*

```js
import { resolve } from "path";

export class RoutesCrud {
  static handle(nuxt: any) {
    nuxt.hook("pages:extend", async (pages: Array<any>) => {
      pages.push({
        name: "crud2",
        path: "/crud2",
        file: resolve("/components/crud/AppCrud.vue"),
        children: await deep1(),
      });
    });
  }
}

async function deep1() {
  return [
    {
      name: "CrudPath",
      path: "/crud2/:path",
      file: resolve("/components/crud/deep1/CrudDeep1List.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          name: "CrudDeep1Id",
          path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id",
          file: resolve("/components/crud/deep1/CrudDeep1Form.vue"),
          children: await deep2(),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

async function deep2() {
  return [
    {
      name: "CrudDeep2Path",
      path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path",
      file: resolve("/components/crud/deep2/CrudDeep2List.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          name: "CrudDeep2Id",
          path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id",
          file: resolve("/components/crud/deep2/CrudDeep2Form.vue"),
          children: await deep3(),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

async function deep3() {
  return [
    {
      name: "CrudDeep3Path",
      path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id/:deep3Path",
      file: resolve("/components/crud/deep3/CrudDeep3List.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          name: "CrudDeep3Id",
          path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id/:deep3Path/:deep3Id",
          file: resolve("/components/crud/deep3/CrudDeep3Form.vue"),
          children: await deep4(),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

async function deep4() {
  return [
    {
      name: "CrudDeep4Path",
      path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id/:deep3Path/:deep3Id/:deep4Path",
      file: resolve("/components/crud/deep4/CrudDeep4List.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          name: "CrudDeep4Id",
          path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id/:deep3Path/:deep3Id/:deep4Path/:deep4Id",
          file: resolve("/components/crud/deep4/CrudDeep4Form.vue"),
          children: await deep5(),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

// eslint-disable-next-line require-await
async function deep5() {
  return [
    {
      name: "CrudDeep5Path",
      path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id/:deep3Path/:deep3Id/:deep4Path/:deep4Id/:deep5Path",
      file: resolve("/components/crud/deep5/CrudDeep5List.vue"),
      children: [
        {
          name: "CrudDeep5Id",
          path: "/crud2/:path/:deep1Id/:deep2Path/:deep2Id/:deep3Path/:deep3Id/:deep4Path/:deep4Id/:deep5Path/:deep5Id",
          file: resolve("/components/crud/deep5/CrudDeep5Form.vue"),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

*In the nuxt.config.ts, import the class.*

```js
import { RoutesCrud } from "./extends/pages/RoutesCrud";
...
modules: [
...
  // Inject pages:extend to nuxt hooks
  async (options, nuxt) => {
    await RoutesCrud.handle(nuxt);
  },

...
]
```

In this way, it is possible to hierarchically load the components only when the specific parameter is informed. Each parent component rendered before the child. Generating a view with all aggregated components. I believe that this way it is very easy to create more dynamic pages using only the routing system.